# autohotkey scroll feature

Tags: autohotkey, scrolling

I recently got a trackball that does not have a scroll option. I don't know if this is possible but is there a way to detect if the trackball is being moved while a key is being pressed (lets say the alt key), stop the mouse from moving and scroll according to the direction of the trackball?

I found a way to detect a change in the cursor position but not a change in the mouse position. I also did not find a way to stop the cursor from moving.

Can you help?

Comment: Could you post what you already have?

Comment: Since I don't know all of the commands necessary I just have some pseudocode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this on the AutoHotkey forums and modified it to include horizontal scrolling.  Holding down alt and moving the mouse will perform a scroll in the direction of the mouse movement.

```
~*Alt::
    Loop
    {
       If !GetKeyState("Alt","P")
          break
       MouseGetPos, ax,ay
       Sleep, 50
       MouseGetPos,bx,by
       Send % (ay<by ? "{WheelDown " : "{WheelUp ") . round(Abs(ay-by)/(GetKeyState("Shift","P") ? 10 : 1)) . "}"
       Send % (ax<bx ? "{WheelRight " : "{WheelLeft ") . round(Abs(ax-bx)/(GetKeyState("Shift","P") ? 10 : 1)) . "}"
    }
Return
```

[Source](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=47054)